# Unexpected server reset with php and apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache, debugging

I have an application which interacts with a database. Suddenly and occasionally, pages are showing me `Server connection Reset` error in my Web browser. More surpisingly, accessing on a `localhost` page is triggering an alert on avast.

If I refresh pages using `Ctrl+R`, it happens occasionally. PHP is not showing any error messages, and it seems like the server is taking more time to respond than usual.

I am using wamp with apache 2.4, PHP 5.4.3. I am clueless as to where to start debugging or where to the problem is.

```
[Sun May 13 13:01:14 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun May 13 13:01:14 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 13 13:01:14 2012] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 12:51:11
[Sun May 13 13:01:14 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3660
Apache server interrupted...
arn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun May 13 13:01:15 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Child process is running
[Sun May 13 13:01:15 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun May 13 13:01:15 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun May 13 13:01:15 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun May 13 13:01:15 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun May 13 13:01:28 2012] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun May 13 13:01:28 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Sun May 13 13:01:29 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Released the start mutex
[Sun May 13 13:01:30 2012] [notice] Child 3660: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun May 13 13:01:30 2012] [notice] Child 3660: Child process is exiting
[Sun May 13 13:01:30 2012] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

**UPDATE:**

When 'connection request' occurs if is use `cachegrind` it shows partial list of callstack of methods. means it does not run all the code. it is showing some require_once calls and that it. next time if i retry to get the page, page executes and shows the whole callstack.

When 'connection request occurs' it shows

```
18 different functions called in milliseconds (1 runs, 18 shown)
```

after retrying

```
220 different functions called in 329 milliseconds (2 runs, 220 shown)
```

I dont know why it is showing 2 runs. also it is taking more time to execute page. before it was doing it less than 100 ms.

Comment: what say apache logs?

Comment: avast as in the anti virus program?? crikey, what does that message say?

Comment: @CodeMonkey yes the anti virus. it is saying  'malicious url has been blocked'

Comment: @mkjasinski it has no error

Comment: Does the Server Reset always correspond with avast's warnings? I used to use avast and I don't remember it ever blocking any of my stuff, getting that error would cause me concern! what does/should the blocked urls return?

Comment: Both are happening occasionaly even if i run the same pages. also i noticed the url in avast alert is being changed to www.localhost.com/Rest/of/the/url even though i was just refreshed the the page which was just localhost/rest/of/the/url

Comment: @CodeMonkey No not always. both are happening randomly/occasionally. i am so confused

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you looked up the server's error logs (NOT access logs)?

Comment: @holodoc yes. if you want to see the dump of the file. ihave updated the OP

Comment: Do you have access to another computer than you can access your wamp server from, see if that has the same issue? Is the rest of your internet access fine? I would be tempted to run malwarebytes to see if there is anything interfering, check hosts file, proxy settings etc. If everything seems fine, I would be tempted to disable avast for a while and see if the problem goes away

Comment: @CodeMonkey i will try your ways. rest of the internet access is fine. Is it possible that code of mine messed somewhere which is causing this?

Comment: it is possible, but without seeing the code or the data that it intends to return, i would just be guessing.

Comment: Do you use `include` command for connecting to the db? like `include('db_connect.php')` (contains all db connection statements). if yes , use `include_once('db_connect.php')`

Comment: @amir all class are included using *_once()

Comment: I dont understand one more thing if there is anything with memory overflow, why dont it show any max memory out error.

Comment: Looks like you are using SSL, do you need it? If not, disable it as you may have config error somewhere in the setup

Comment: I suspect that Apache is trying to use more resource so either your operating system or the antivirus is sending the kill single to prevent it from getting more resources. Check the allowed number of threads in your Apache config also add Apache in your antivirus safe list.

Comment: @fallenAngel If it's a stack overflow error inside a external library routine, PHP wouldn't catch the error. It'll just kill the server process. Check to see if you have an infinite recursion somewhere.

Comment: @cleong can you explain what do you mean by `extrenal library routine`?

Comment: You can try changing Apache listen ports to see what will happen in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart you computer and close/disable all running applications including anti-virus keeping only a minimal set of running applications. Close everything even those applications that you are sure can't interfere - you never know..
2. Make sure PHP shows all errors/warnings:

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');
   ```

Make sure you review every warning you receive from PHP. It may give you a clue.

1. Try to isolate a problem. Comment a chunk of code you suspect to cause the problem. Keep commenting until stop receive the error. Then start uncommenting until you find a problematic place. This way you can isolate a problematic code and once you see it, you may understand the problem.
2. Add lots of statements that will write to log file (or just echo). Then you can analyze the log file and understand at which point error happens helping you to isolate the problem...

Eventually you will find the problematic code block and will be able to track the problem. Hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

to restart Apache via PHP use the follow code in PHP

```
exec('/etc/init.d/httpd graceful');
```

and also look in the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/stopping.html#graceful)... and change the path to your httpd

Comment: and on a side note if your server allows you to restart it by calling an arbitrary script that normally needs to be run by the superuser from inside it, I would be very afraid..)

Answer (score 0):

Change apache listen port from 80 to 8080
file `httpd.conf` , change `listen 80` to `listen 8080` and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Re-try disabling temporarly the antivirus

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not a right solution, but why not just try other WAMP version or maybe setup your system clock correct?. **And have you tried to run Apache in minimal configuration?** You may disable all extensions and modules (inc php itself) and if web server will work as expected you may turn one by one you modules. I don't know about your environment but you may also try to change working threads number and other values to minimal. I bet it doesn't help but at least you'll try.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mod_security enabled try disabling and see if the same happens.. sometimes you can have over vigilant mod_security that will just go to http fail (sometimes can be as simple as inserting data with an ampersand into the database) and won't write any error to the server logs making it hard to troubleshoot, sounds similar to what you're experiencing, I would disable mod_security re-start server and see if the behavior has stopped!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some other people have encountered the same issue using Wamp:
Have you gone through each of the points enumerated in this post belonging to the official forum:

http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,67660

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have an include/require loop ?

That kind of loop make PHP eat up too much memory and apache kill itself to avoid it.

Or maybe some kind of 404 loop error ... 
That kind of loop can happen if you have 404 errors sometimes. Here is an example :

You have a layout with an image which is missing, so it triggers a 404 errors. To display the page, the 404 errors add the layout around the error page which contains the missing image, which triggers another 404 errors.

Hope that helps.